# ffmpeg memery leak with av_read_frame

Tags: memory-leaks, ffmpeg

I use av_read_frame in two ways below:

1.

```
for(;;){
        if (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, packet) >= 0){
            av_packet_unref(packet);
        }
    }
```

2.

```
   for(;;){
        packet = av_packet_alloc();
        if (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, packet) >= 0){
            av_packet_free(&packet);
        }
    }
```

Noting to do but read file and call free methods with FFMPEG APIs.
Both have a memery leak problem.(1.72GB film file got 300MB memory increment)
Anyone got rosulation?